Tailwind config is not respected in nuxt 3, my config options are ignored, I would like to limit tailwind to my content paths
I set up tailwind in my nuxt project and it works great to use basic tailwind styles. But the problem is I can not make any modifications to the tailwind config like changing the content paths. It seems nuxt is auto generated its own config in the .nuxt folder and ignoring and config options. This makes tailwind highly unusable as I can not make any customizations.  I've tried a variety of set ups and cannot get my customizations to the content path to be respected in the config.
my set up is as follows
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  pages: true,
    modules: [
        'nuxt-icon',
        'nuxt-lodash',
        '@pinia/nuxt',
        '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
        '@nuxtjs/supabase'
    ],
    css: [
      '~/assets/css/global.css'  
    ],
    tailwindcss: {
      configPath: "./tailwind.config.ts",
      exposeConfig:true,
      viewer: true,
      config: {
        jit: true,
        content: [
        ],
      }
    },  

tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./pages/tailwind/**"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}



I've also tried the method of manually including @tailwinds imports and linking that to my css as well as few othe methods and configs I tried online, such as using auto prefixer and post css in the config as well. No matter what tailwind will not respect my config.
In the .nuxt folder it auto generates these files which seem to override my config options

I would like to make changes to tailwind config, specifically to exclude tailwind from modifiying certain pages and components.

The configPath in nuxt.config is tailwind.config.ts , but the actual file is tailwind.config.js, maybe this is why it doesn't respect the tailwind config file.
